# Generate encrypted password for a GNU screen session

Tags: encryption, gnu-screen, password-generation

How to programatically generate a password for a [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) session?

Normally, to define a password for an existing GNU screen, we have to:

- Start a screen
- Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>:password</kbd>
- Upon reattach, screen will ask for the password

And to apply the password to new screen sessions:

- Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>
- Copy the encrypted password
- Put the encrypted password in `~/.screenrc`  (or some custom file) preceded by `password` statement
- Upon next start (`screen -c "/path/to/custom_screenrc` for custom files), screen will ask for the password

That's a lot of manual steps to have an encrypted password generated.

I want to run a command to generate the encrypted password to be put in `.screenrc`.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial! Your question was enough to what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU screen uses GNU crypt C library ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28C%29), [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt)) with DES encryption and a random  salt comprised of 2 random uppercase alphabetic characters.

So, let's use `mkpasswd` from `whois` package that relies on the same library:

`sudo apt-get install whois`

Then generate the encrypted password:

```
(echo -n "password "; mkpasswd -m des -S SO "test") >> ~/.screenrc
```

Next time you'll start a new screen, it will ask for the password.

Alternative to apply the password only to certain (new) screens:

```
tmpconfig="$(mktemp /tmp/.screenrc-XXXXXX)"
(echo -n "password "; mkpasswd -m des -S SO "test") > "$tmpconfig"
screen -c "$tmpconfig"
rm "$tmpconfig"
```

You can safely delete the temp config file once screen is started. Encrypted password is stored in memory once started.

Note:

- `test` is the password.
- `SO` is the salt. You can keep this salt, or replace it by whatever 2 uppercase alphabtetic characters, i.e. `^[A-Z]{2,2}$` in regexp language. Just for info (and for brute-forcers), the first two characters of the encrypted password is indeed the salt.
- For a small added security of temporary screen conf files, store it in RAM instead of hard drive, by using [`/run/shm`](https://askubuntu.com/a/169526/263353) instead of `/tmp`.